# Файлы по прошествии времени не могут быть удалены средствами C++/WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi

Столкнулся со странной проблемой.

Имеется некий самодельный инсталлятор на чистом С++/WinAPI, который из zip-архива, содержащегося в ресурсе exe-шника, разархивирует группу файлов в указанный каталог. При этом, если файлы существуют, сначала он их удаляет (для эксперимента даже сделал поочередно удаление функцией DeleteFile из WinBase.h и функцией remove из stdio.h). Обнаружил, что по прошествии определенного времени (более месяца) существующие файлы перестают удаляться, функция DeleteFile не отрабатывает, а код системной ошибки GetLastError равен 0x5 ("отказано в доступе"). При этом, если проинсталлировать файлы в другой каталог, а потом сразу же попробовать проинсталлировать в него же повторно, то все файлы успешно удаляются и пересоздаются. Т.е. DeleteFile отрабатывает.

Я также сравнил свойства файла, который не может быть удален, со свойствами файла, который успешно удаляется, и не обнаружил никаких различий во вкладке "безопасность" между правами на файл для групп и пользователей. Компьютер не в домене, пользователь всего один, и учетная запись не менялась уже несколько лет. Никаких действий с учетной записью тоже не проводилось.

Инсталлятор использует библиотеку XUnzip с открытым кодом, и я проверил, что при разархивировании файлы создаются следующим вызовом функции:

```
CreateFile(FullFileName, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS,
   FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE|FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
```

Между тем, файлы, которые создавались моим инсталлятором, но в последствии не могут быть им удалены/пересозданы, спокойно удаляются любым другим способом - через проводник или, например, Total Commander.

Проблема не только на моем компьютере, но и на многих других компьютерах. Как минимум, она повторяется на WinXP, Win7 и Win10.

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, на что обратить внимание. Может, есть версии возможных причин. Спасибо.

Comment: Инсталлятор запускается с правами админа?

Comment: Как вариант, эти файлы спустя какое-то время приобретают зависимости с другими программами/файлами?

Comment: Да. Текущий пользователь локальный администратор. Кроме того, в свойствах проекта Visual Studio 2010 "Компоновщик"->"Файл манифеста"->"Уровень выполнения UAC" я установил requireAdministrator (/level='requireAdministrator'). Но это не помогает. Никаких зависимостей со временем файлы не приобретают, они используются только для чтения некоторым приложением, устанавливаемым инсталлятором.

Comment: Не может это быть как-то связано с флагом FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE при вызове CreateFile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел причину. Не заметил сразу, что на файлах появились атрибуты "только для чтения". Откуда они взялись, я не знаю, но теперь перед удалением файлов я делаю вызов

```
SetFileAttributes(FullFileName,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL);
```

и все нормально удаляется.